# Virtualization Options on Windows 7 for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I am running Windows 7 x64. I want to make a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 virtual machine so I can try out Sharepoint development.

I have heard that Hyper-V is not supported on Windows 7.

So what is supported on Windows 7?

**Note: I need a solution that is free for commercial use or is a Microsoft Product.**

Comment: Why you need "free for commercial use"? Development is not considred commercial use in most cases. Either you use the virtual machine to develop on, or you deploy and then you have the world upside with a WIndows7 host.

Comment: @TomTom - I did not know that Development is not considered commercial use.  If that is the case I can just pick either VM Ware or Virtual Box.

Comment: It mostly is. Particularities depend, but for example MSDN is clearly "not for commmercial use" but "for development". Testing and development are often separate items from "running a production system = commercial use". Check the licensing conditions.

Answer (score 1):

No such platform exists for Windows 7.

**VMWare:** Anything commercial is pay-for.
**Sun VirtualBox:** License specifically states commercial deployments are not free.
**Xen:** Doesn't run on Windows.
**Hyper-V:** Only runs on Server 2008.
**Virtual PC:** What came before Hyper-V, spotty Windows 7 support, and still not free for commercial use.

Unfortunately, if Commercial = true, then payFor also = true.

The one exception is VirtualBox open-source-edition. There are no pre-compiled binaries that I can find (that doesn't mean they can't be dug up, though), but if you want to take a whack at compiling your own you can do so [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), under the VirtualBox Sources section. VirtualBox-OSE is GPLed, unlike the binary distribution which is under a different license and excludes commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

For Testing purpose only you can use VMWare Player. It's free and also works on Windows 7 32 bit and 64 bit.